# Jupyter Notebook Slides in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, slideshow

In `Jupyter Notebook` we could create slides, like explained [here](https://medium.com/@mjspeck/presenting-code-using-jupyter-notebook-slides-a8a3c3b59d67). Here you can see a reproducible example to create Jupyter notebook slides via Anaconda-navigator:

[image]

When running this command in the terminal:

```
jupyter nbconvert slides_test.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

It will outputs this in your browser:

[image]

And for the code cell output:

[image]

This is very nice and I would like to use this but in `VScode`.

In the Jupyter notebook of Anaconda navigator we can create slides when clicking on `View` -> `Cell Toolbar` -> `Slideshow` in the header bar. Unfortunately, this is not possible in VScode. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to create Jupyter Notebook slides in VScode?

Comment: It seems there is a VSCode extension to use slides: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow . I haven't tried it though...maybe it's worth taking a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, ensure that you have install [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter).

[image]

It will install several extensions required for Jupyter including slides for you.

Then, you can add a slide type to the cell you're on by opening the Command Palette **(Cmd+Shift+P)** and selecting **Switch Slide Type** according to the document in [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-jupyter-slideshow).

[image]

[image]

You could modify slide types for notebook cells by selecting the slide type on the cell.

[image]

After assigning slide types to your cells, create an HTML slideshow presentation by opening the integrated terminal and running the command, `jupyter nbconvert '<notebook-file-name>.ipynb' --to slides --post serve`.